# Relationship between fundamental polygon and its side edges

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Here is the fundamental polygon diagram for torus and the diagram for its edge of the square region:

[image]

My question is why the direction of loops in both circles in the right diagram must be clockwise. Why the "flipping" for just one circle is not allowed? How can I deduce the correct direction of loops in the right diagram from the left fundamental polygon?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the right diagram? Is it just the 1-skeleton of the torus (induced by the side-pairing on the square)?

Comment: @DanielRust The right diagram is the representation of 4 edges of left diagram by gluing 4 vertices of left diagram (which is actually one point in the torus). Is that diagram called 1-skeleton?

Comment: You just have to follow the lines of the polygon to construct your 1-skeleton.

Comment: @user40276 How can I do this? Starting from taking the upper red line, and then.. Please help me to figure out the exact correspondence between two diagram.

Comment: Ok, first of all, can you understand why do you have only 1 point? If you can understand it, just start by this point in the polygon and then follow the lines(imagine you're walking along the lines) in the polygon (in the clockwise direction or counter-clockwise if you want).

Comment: @user40276 OK.. from red line, I got the vertice 1=3, 2=4 and from blue line, I got the vertice 3=4, 1=2, and hence 1=2=3=4, but since the clockwise direction of red and blue is different, so the right diagram is glued two circle, not just a big one circle, and actually the orientation of each circle is not important. I got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think that flipping one of the circles is not allowed? if you imagine these circles embedded in the torus as the meridional and longitudinal circles, you see that they intersect orthogonally at the single $0$-cell. Given this, there's really no *correct* orientation to put them in when projecting onto a plane.

Comment: But in the case of Klein bottle (which direction of two "red line" differs), the direction of one loop of two circles in the right diagram was clockwise, and the remaining one was counterclockwise. If there is no correct (at least up to total flip) orientation, then why these difference occurs?

Comment: The orientation of the circles for the Klein bottle is also not important. What **is** important is the way that you then glue a disk along those circles. One way will give a torus - another way will give a Klein bottle.